# App crash while trying to load the model to mlkit.vision using firebase

Tags: android, tensorflow, firebase-mlkit, google-mlkit

I have followed the guide:
[ML - Custom Object detector](https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/vision/object-detection/custom-models/android)

While using remote model, downloaded by firebase.

I get the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalAccessError: Illegal class access: 'com.google.mlkit.vision.objects.custom.internal.zze' attempting to access 'com.google.mlkit.vision.vkp.zzb' (declaration of 'com.google.mlkit.vision.objects.custom.internal.zze' appears in /data/app/~~RSIsdNozReDcbSJphl3n-w==/com.xxx.xxx-VTfH5rUrQwCnHUXsLKVb4A==/base.apk!classes4.dex)
                            at com.google.mlkit.vision.objects.custom.internal.zze.tryLoad(SourceFile:437)
                            at com.google.mlkit.common.sdkinternal.model.CustomModelLoader.load(SourceFile:43)
                            at com.google.mlkit.vision.objects.custom.internal.zzf.load(SourceFile:13)
                            at com.google.mlkit.common.sdkinternal.zzn.run(SourceFile:32)
                            at com.google.mlkit.common.sdkinternal.zzt.run(SourceFile:12)
                            at com.google.mlkit.common.sdkinternal.zzk.run(SourceFile:24)
                            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
                            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:644)
                            at com.google.mlkit.common.sdkinternal.zzi.run(SourceFile:13)
                            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012)
```

but only on release/non debugable version.
Setting the following do not crash my app:

```
minifyEnabled true
shrinkResources true
debuggable true
```

removing the `debuggable true` - does.

I use mostly the mlkit, which works fine. I have added fire base - tensor flow model downloader, when I set to download the model from the firebase, in release mode - it crashes.
this is my build.gradle, maybe something is conflicting in the references?

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-mlkit-face-detection:17.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-mlkit-image-labeling:16.0.8'
implementation 'com.google.mlkit:linkfirebase:17.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.mlkit:object-detection-custom:17.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.mlkit:playstore-dynamic-feature-support:16.0.0-beta2'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:18.2.0'


implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:28.1.0')
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'

implementation 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite:2.4.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-modeldownloader:24.1.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-ktx:21.2.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:20.3.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config-ktx:21.3.0'
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:18.0.2"
constraints {
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.8.0") {
        because("kotlin-stdlib-jdk7 is now a part of kotlin-stdlib")
    }
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.8.0") {
        because("kotlin-stdlib-jdk8 is now a part of kotlin-stdlib")
    }
}
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-mlkit-text-recognition:18.0.2'
```

this is the code - the crash happens after the line :
"loadTesnsor::tensor model loaded::7"

```
AppendLogDebug("loadTesnsor::tensor model loaded::5");
           com.google.mlkit.vision.objects.custom.CustomObjectDetectorOptions  customObjectDetectorOptions =
                        new com.google.mlkit.vision.objects.custom.CustomObjectDetectorOptions.Builder(remoteModel)
                                .setDetectorMode(CustomObjectDetectorOptions.STREAM_MODE)
                                .enableClassification()
                                .setClassificationConfidenceThreshold(0.5f)
                                .setMaxPerObjectLabelCount(3)
                                .build();
            AppendLogError("loadTesnsor::tensor model loaded::6");
            com.google.mlkit.vision.objects.ObjectDetector  objectDetector =
                    com.google.mlkit.vision.objects.ObjectDetection.getClient(customObjectDetectorOptions);
            AppendLogError("loadTesnsor::tensor model loaded::7");
            objectDetector
                    .process(img)
                    .addOnCompleteListener(e -> {
                        mProcessing.set(false);
                        AppendLogError("loadTesnsor::tensor model loaded::132");
                    })
                    .addOnFailureListener(e -> {
                        mProcessing.set(false);
                        AppendLogError("loadTesnsor::tensor model loaded::11");
                    })
                    .addOnSuccessListener(results -> {
                        AppendLogError("loadTesnsor::tensor model loaded::12");
                        try {
                            if (results != null && !results.isEmpty()) {
                                try {
                                    AppendLogError("loadTesnsor::tensor model loaded::9");
                                    InitOnce();
                                    AppendLogError("loadTesnsor::tensor model loaded::10");
                                    
                                    
                                } catch (Exception ex) {
                                    AppendLogError(ex.toString());
                                }


                            } else
                                AppendLogError("loadTesnsor::tensor model loaded::8");
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            AppendLogError(ex.toString());
                        }
                        mProcessing.set(false);
                    })
```

My service is a background service,
I have checked if changing to UI thread helps - it doesn't.
I am using InputImage.fromByteArray after getting YUV images and transferring it to NV21(using YUV420toNV21)

updating to local asset location did not help.

```
localModel = new LocalModel.Builder().setAssetFilePath("object_labeler.tflite")
```

UPDATE - SOLUTION:
It looks like it was fixed by adding the following to pro-guard (which was not mention in any of the tutorial or examples)

```
-keep class com.google.mlkit.common.** { *; }
-keep class com.google.mlkit.vision.** { *; }
```

I am leaving this question here - in case someone bump into this problem.